# Force encrypted network traffic with Oracle thin client and jdbc?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

Is there a way to force encryption of network traffic (that is, result set data) using Oracle thin client and jdbc?

I understand that this can be done by setting up a java.util.Properties object and passing that to DriverManager.getConnection( String, Properties), but is there a way to specify this in the jdbc url?

I'm using a third party tool written in Java, which handles creating its own connections, so creating and passing the Properties object won't work for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [Oracle JDBC documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/toc.htm). There is a chapter about [Client Side Security Features](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/clntsec.htm#CIHBIEHA), that talks about using system properties to configure a Thin Driver for SSL.

Comment: Question asks specifically about how to set this in **URL**. The docs you refer to talks about how to set this using properties, but not how to do it via the URL.